# No console output using log4j2 and slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

am I missing something using this configuration? I thought that root logger would log all events from error level to the bottom one. If I try to log event at info level, there is no output. This config gives me only error leveled logs. I am using slf4j to create logger objects through Logger-factory class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For info level logs, change the configuration, in particular Root level to info as show below

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

By changing level to info, the program will start logging both info, error logs in the console.